# Restricting access to a wesbite from a particular machine

Tags: java, php, servlets

How to restrict access to the site from a particular machine, so that the page is always  accessed from a particular machine only.

Comment: Do you mean how to allow access to only one machine?

Comment: This site should be taken from only one machine by a valid user.I am able to validate the user, but need to authenticate if the site is accessed from a particular  client machine alone. I can't rely on ip address as they are dynamic

Comment: I would suggest that you'll need to use SSL and then require that the remote machine have an SSL *client* certificate to verify its authenticity, because anything else that comes to mind could be spoofed; at this point, though, that may not exactly be a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `getRemoteAddr()` available in `ServletRequest`, to find which IP is trying to access your site and block if necessary.

**Useful Links:**

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19857-01/821-0980/bhaip/index.html